# Evaluating the parametric representation of a surface

Tags: calculus

Trying to find the parametric representation of the following surface:

the cap of the sphere $ x^2+y^2+z^2=16 $ for $ 4/\sqrt2\le z \le4 $

my solution:

I see that :

$ x = \sqrt{16-y^2+z^2}$

$ y = \sqrt{16-x^2+z^2}$

$z = \sqrt{16-x^2-y^2}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameterization of a sphere of radius $\rho$ is given by

$$x = \rho \cos\theta \sin \phi$$
$$y = \rho \sin \theta \sin \phi$$
$$z = \rho \cos \phi$$

where $0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$ and $0 \leq \phi \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$. Then, as $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 4^2$ we impose that $\rho = 4$, now we need only incorporate the constraint $\frac{4}{\sqrt{2}} \leq z \leq 4$. Since $z = 4\cos \phi$ we get

$$z = 4\cos \phi = 4 \hspace{10mm}\text{ implies } \hspace{10mm} \phi = 0$$

$$z = 4\cos \phi = \frac{4}{\sqrt{2}} \hspace{10mm} \text{ implies } \hspace{10mm} \phi = \frac{\pi}{4}$$

Where we have used a special triangle for the equation $\cos \phi = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. Thus the parameterization is given by

$$x = 4\cos \theta \sin \phi$$
$$y = 4 \sin \theta \sin \phi$$
$$z = 4 \cos \phi$$

where $0\leq \theta \leq \pi$ and $0 \leq \phi \leq \frac{\pi}{4}$.

Comment: awesome thanks for your input, your answer is different then @breeze

Comment: Yes, this is because @breeze is using Cartesian coordinates, which do not cause a problem in this situation because you are looking for part of half a sphere. Still, in practice, this Spherical coordinate representation (although equivalent) is easier to work with.

Comment: okay so both answers would be correct then?

Comment: Yes, both answers are correct.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{array}{l}x = r\cos (\theta )\\y = r\sin (\theta )\\\theta  \in [0,2\pi ]\\z = \sqrt {(16 - {x^2} - {y^2})}  = \sqrt {(16 - {r^2})} \\\sqrt 8  = 4/\sqrt 2  \le z \le 4 \Rightarrow \\0 \le r \le \sqrt 8 \end{array}
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaagKart1ev2aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbefMDPr
% garuavP1wzZbItLDhis9wBH5garmWu51MyVXgaruWqVvNCPvMCG4uz
% 3bqee0evGueE0jxyaibaieYlf9irVeeu0dXdh9vqqj-hEeeu0xXdbb
% a9frFj0-OqFfea0dXdd9vqaq-JfrVkFHe9pgea0dXdar-Jb9hs0dXd
% bPYxe9vr0-vr0-vqpWqaaiaaciWacmaadaGabiaaeaGaauaaaOabae
% qabaGaamiEaiabg2da9iaadkhaciGGJbGaai4BaiaacohacaGGOaGa
% eqiUdeNaaiykaaqaaiaadMhacqGH9aqpcaWGYbGaci4CaiaacMgaca
% GGUbGaaiikaiabeI7aXjaacMcaaeaacqaH4oqCcqGHiiIZcaGGBbGa
% aGimaiaacYcacaaIYaGaeqiWdaNaaiyxaaqaaiaadQhacqGH9aqpda
% GcaaqaaiaacIcacaaIXaGaaGOnaiabgkHiTiaadIhadaahaaWcbeqa
% aabaaaaaaaaapeGaaGOmaaaak8aacqGHsislcaWG5bWaaWbaaSqabe
% aapeGaaGOmaaaakiaacMcaaSWdaeqaaOGaeyypa0ZaaOaaaeaacaGG
% OaGaaGymaiaaiAdacqGHsislcaWGYbWaaWbaaSqabeaapeGaaGOmaa
% aak8aacaGGPaaaleqaaaGcbaWdbmaakaaabaGaaGioaaWcbeaakiab
% g2da9iaaisdacaGGVaWaaOaaa8aabaWdbiaaikdaaSqabaGccqGHKj
% YOcaWG6bGaeyizImQaaGinaiabgkDiEdqaaiaaicdacqGHKjYOcaWG
% YbGaeyizIm6aaOaaaeaacaaI4aaaleqaaaaaaa!768A!
$$